# Brainfuck interpreter has peculiar problems with loops

Tags: c++, interpreter, brainfuck

I am writing a cpp program to execute live inputs of Brainfuck code,
like how you can use python live in a terminal.

Everything works fine, except when nested loops come into play:

This nested loop works fine:

`++++++++[>++++[>++>+++>+++>+<<<<-]>+>+>->>+[<]<-]>>.>---.+++++++..+++.>>.<-.<.+++.------.--------.>>+.>++.`

while this doesn't:

`+[-[<<[+[--->]-[<<<]]]>>>-]>-.---.>..>.<<<<-.<+.>>>>>.>.<<.<-.`

The first one outputs "Hello World!" as expected, whilst the other one outputs random gibberish.

My program just rolls back the index `i`, which loops through the code, to the right bracket, it finds the right bracket to roll back to with the counter `bi` that starts as a 1, and every time a ']' is detected it increases by one, and every time a '[' is detected it decreases.

So my program just needs to roll back until it finds an '[' and `bi` is 0, but apparently either my idea has flaws, or i didn't code it correctly. Hope you could help me find out.

I tested the other commands thoroughly, so i think you'll only need to look at the last else if, which catches the ']'.

Brief variable explanation: `tp` is the array representing the memory used by Brainfuck; `ptr` is the index representing the pointer in memory; `inpt` is the string of Brainfuck code inputted by the user; `i` is the index looping through the code; `bi` is the bracket counter explained earlier.

P.S. Please note that optimization still wasn't taken into account in this program, first I want it to work, then I'll try and optimize it.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
constexpr int tpSIZE = 30000;

int main() {
    int ptr = 0;
    unsigned char tp[tpSIZE] = { 0 };
    std::string inpt = "";
    do {
        std::cout << "|BF|";
        std::cin >> inpt;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < inpt.size()) {
            if (inpt[i] == '>' || inpt[i] == '<') { ptr = inpt[i] == '>' ? (ptr+1)%tpSIZE : ptr-1; if(ptr==-1) ptr = tpSIZE-1; }
            else if (inpt[i] == '-' || inpt[i] == '+') tp[ptr] += inpt[i] == '+' ? 1 : -1;
            else if (inpt[i] == '.') std::cout << tp[ptr];
            else if (inpt[i] == ',') std::cin >> tp[ptr];
            else if (inpt[i] == ']' && tp[ptr] != 0) {
                int bi = 1;
                while (inpt[i] != '[' || bi != 0) {
                    if (inpt[i-1] == ']') bi++;
                    else if (inpt[i-1] == '[') bi--;
                    i--;
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
    } while (inpt != "q");
}
```

Comment: I don't think the problem is the closing `]`  I think it is the opening `[` because according to https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck "`[` Jumps past the matching `]` if the cell at the pointer is 0" but your code doesn't do anything with `[` at all.